# Убрать custom css код с блока head в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Добавила custom css в админ панели сайта на Wordpress:

```
.top-header {
    background: #40E0D0;
}


.main-listing {
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
```

И теперь если открыть view-source сайта, он отображается в head:

```
<style id='pony-style-inline-css' type='text/css'>

.top-header {
    background: #40E0D0;
}


.main-listing {
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
</style>
```

Что сделать чтобы он не генерировался туда? Возможно что-то в functions.php нужно прописать?

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? И куда он "должен генерироваться"?

Comment: Он не должен генерироваться в блок <head> </head> так же как и куча другого кода css не генерируется в блок <head> </head>

Comment: Можно ж как-то с помощью строки remove_action () добавить в functions.php чтобы не генерировался данный css код в хедер?

Comment: А чему мешает этот css в header?

Comment: минус для скорости загрузки сайта (css стили в хедере) и для красоты хедера в целом.

Comment: Краста эта никому не нужна. А минус в скорости вообще не существует. Ну, поставите вы стили в style.css. И будут они выведены через `<link rel='stylesheet' ... ` внутри `<head>...</head>`. Не в футер же вы стили закинете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что сделать чтобы он не генерировался туда? Возможно что-то в
>   functions.php нужно прописать?

[Подключить свой css-файл](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/). Но лучше создать [дочернюю тему](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) и прописать стили в ней.

*И хотя дочернюю тему нужно делать почти всегда, но точно не из-за того, что стили присутствуют в хедере.*

Comment: Плюсанул )) ...